# show result through function

Tags: php, forms, function, submit

How to show the result with submitting value from FORM?

```
<?php
    function db(){ 
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die("Cannot connect to the database server now". mysql_error());

    mysql_select_db('bkd_rev',$conn) or die("Error in selecting database now ".mysql_errno());
      return $conn;  
    }
        function result(){
            $conn = db();

                    $q1  = mysql_query("select sum(value_skp)/count(skp)*0.6 AS Result from tbl_skp where y_skp=".$_POST['year']." AND id='197411222008011004'");
                    if (!$q1)
                        die("Error : ".mysql_error());

                        if($row = mysql_fetch_array($q1))
                        echo "SKP : ".$row['Result']."<br>";

            }
?>
<form method="post" name="form_input" onsubmit="return result()">
    <select class="reqname" name="year" >
                            <option value="#">=== select year===</option>
                            <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                            <option value="2016">2016</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="result" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

It works fine with `isset` but I'm trying another way with `function` but no result (blank) after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the result() function (like you have called the db() function in your result function).